# Conditional logic in T-SQL select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a database in SQL Server 2014, I have a `CustomerRecords` table with address columns `Address`, `City`, `State`, `Zip`.

I also have a `CustomerBillingAddresses` table with an FK relation to `CustomerRecords` on `CustomerID`. This table also contains the `Address, City, State, Zip` columns, but additionally has an `Active` (bit) column. Each `CustomerID` can have only one record that is active.

Not all `CustomerRecords` are in `CustomerBillingAddresses` and not all records in `CustomerBillingAddresses` are active (`Active=1`)

I want to return the customer info like this:

```
CustomerID, Name, Address, City, State, Zip
```

But I only want to return a single set of address info, either from `CustomerRecords` or `CustomerBillingAddresses` if the `Active` bit is true in CBA.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    cr.CustomerID, cr.CustomerName,
    CASE  
       WHEN cba.CustomerID IS NOT NULL
          THEN cba.Address
          ELSE cr.Address
       END AS Address,
    CASE 
       WHEN cba.CustomerID IS NOT NULL
          THEN cba.City
          ELSE cr.City
       END AS City, 
    CASE 
       WHEN cba.CustomerID IS NOT NULL
          THEN cba.State
          ELSE cr.State
    END AS State, 
    CASE 
       WHEN cba.CustomerID IS NOT NULL
          THEN cba.Zip
          ELSE cr.Zip
    END AS Zip
FROM
    dbo.CustomerRecords cr
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.CustomerBillingAddresses cba ON cba.CustomerID = cr.CustomerID
                                     AND cba.Active = 1
```

I can't exclude CR addresses when an active CBA address is found since they are attached to CustomerID, the base record. I realize that's bad db form but it is what I have to work with. Besides, normalization wouldn't be nearly as fun as this, right?

**QUESTION**

My query actually gets the results I want and doesn't seem to perform much worse than the original query but I'm sure there is a better way.

I cringe seeing "CASE WHEN cba.CustomerID IS NOT NULL" repeated over and over...

I appreciate any assistance, suggestions or answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query gives an impression that if cba.CustomerID is NULL for a row, every other field will be null for the row, and should be ignored.

You can use COALESCE expression in this case.

> [COALESCE expression returns the first non-null expression in the list to be evaluated.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)

```
   SELECT DISTINCT cr.CustomerID, cr.CustomerName, COALESCE(cba.Address, 
   cr.Address) AS Address, 
   COALESCE(cba.City, cr.City) AS City, COALESCE(cba.State, cr.State) AS State, 
   COALESCE(cba.Zip, cr.Zip) AS Zip
    FROM dbo.CustomerRecords cr
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerBillingAddresses cba ON cba.CustomerID = cr.CustomerID
        AND cba.Active = 1
```

Or You can simply use ISNULL function.

> [ISNULL replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql)

```
SELECT DISTINCT cr.CustomerID, cr.CustomerName, ISNULL(cba.Address, 
       cr.Address) AS Address, 
       ISNULL(cba.City, cr.City) AS City, ISNULL(cba.State, cr.State) AS State, 
       ISNULL(cba.Zip, cr.Zip) AS Zip
        FROM dbo.CustomerRecords cr
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerBillingAddresses cba ON cba.CustomerID = cr.CustomerID
            AND cba.Active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If dbo.CustomerBillingAddresses is not nullable, cba.Address is NULL when cba.CustomId is null. So you can check cba.Address directly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cr.CustomerID, cr.CustomerName,
COALESCE(cba.Address, cr.Address) AS Address
...other columns
FROM dbo.CustomerRecords cr
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerBillingAddresses cba ON cba.CustomerID = cr.CustomerID
        AND cba.Active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a way for that, but it might still cringe you, and i don't know about the performance either.

the way is just `union`-ing 2 queries, the first one is for the Active = 0, and the second one is for the Active = 1. you just need to get from the appropriate column. no need for `case when` or `coalesce`

for example:

```
select t1.address, t1.city from table1 t1 where t1.active = 0
union
select t2.address, t2.city from table1 t1 
    inner join table2 t2 on t1.customer = t2.customer where t1.active = 1
```